# Using variable in object name (VBA Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what I want to do:

```
Private Function foo(bar As Integer)
    For n = 0 To ComboBox(bar).ListCount - 1
       [some stuff]
    End For
End Function
```

I'm getting an error on the second line because I'm using (bar), rather than (e.g.) 2, or 3.

Can I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: Sub or Function not defined on the 'Private Function' line. This doesn't happen when I substitute 2 or 3 for '(bar)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on a userform, you can use:

```
For n = 0 To Me.Controls("ComboBox" & bar).ListCount - 1
```

If it is a Worksheet module and an ActiveX combobox, you will need:

```
For n = 0 To Me.OLEObjects("ComboBox" & bar).Object.ListCount - 1
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Method or data member not found', here's my exact code: Private Function isDuplicate(supplier As String, numBox As String) As Boolean

Comment: @TomAlan **Where** is this code located - which module?

Comment: On Sheet1. This sheet also contains all the combobox code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the name of the control to the function:

```
Private Function foo(bar As String)
    For n = 0 To Me.Controls(bar).ListCount -1
       [some stuff]
    Next n 
End Function
```

Or, if you use (for example) ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3 ... ComboBoxN You can do so:

```
Private Function foo(bar As String)
    For n = 0 To Me.Controls("ComboBox" & bar).ListCount -1
       [some stuff]
    Next n 
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Method or data member not found', here's my exact code: Private Function isDuplicate(supplier As String, numBox As String) As Boolean